# "webdev serve" chrome won't show dart source when using https

Tags: https, dart, serve

Trying to test dart app using chrome via https.
(using nginx to proxy https port to webdev serve http port).
When I visit the app using http, I can see main.dart.
When I visit the same app using https, I can see main.dart.js.

Is there a way to get 'webdev serve' listening to a https port ?

[why using https - because google won't allow oauth without it, and anyway, we're supposed to be using https always these days, right?]

Thanks in advance for your help...

Ian

Comment: BTW - talking about dart 2

Comment: same thing here. Need to test oauth of google and facebook and both need https. Even the developer account needs https :(